# How to make SWRevealViewController cover the main view not push it?

Tags: swift3, customization, ios10, swrevealviewcontroller

I was following this tutorial [Customize your SWRevealViewController slide-out menu](http://www.ebc.cat/2015/03/07/customize-your-swrevealviewcontroller-slide-out-menu/)

and this is the layout of the app this how SWReveal push the main View

[image]

but the way Gmail works is to cover the main View like this photo

[image]

and I was wondering if could I make the silde-out menu using SWRevealViewController cover the main view like Gmail app and how to do it ?

Comment: Your question is uncleared.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper answer to my question was opening this issue :
[How to make SWRevealViewController works like covering the main view not as default pushing the main view ? #669](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/669)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only left-menu part is left and menu is sliding on button click.

**Follow below steps :**

1. Take new `UIViewController` in your `storyboard`.
2. Do this
    **a)** Add new `UIView` with size of `UIViewController` (says viewBG). 
    **b)** Now goto property and decrease the `viewBG` opacity according to you, Don't play with alpha value.
    **c)** Take one more view of your left menu (says viewMenu).
3. Add Your `menuVC` as a child VC of your `MainVC`.
4. Now use below line code when you wanted to show menu.

`menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x     : -self.view.frame.size.width,
                                          y     : 0,
                                          width : menuVC.view.frame.size.width,
                                          height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x     : 0,
                                          y     : 0,
                                          width : menuVC.view.frame.size.width,
                                          height: self.view.frame.size.height)
                }`

5. To remove menu

`menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x     : 0,
                                          y     : 0,
                                          width : menuVC.view.frame.size.width,
                                          height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
menuVC.view.frame = CGRect(x     : -self.view.frame.size.width,
                                          y     : 0,
                                          width : menuVC.view.frame.size.width,
                                          height: self.view.frame.size.height)
                }`

**HOPE:** you can give constraints to you view.

Comment: this not with SWRevealViewController library !

Comment: No it is not, but can create same side view like this. and I never used SWRevealVC, so i have no info regarding to it. I just write here my approach. Either you can do like this way and for SW take help from other, :(

Answer (score 0):

The way is to set your "main" view controller as the rearViewController (static, not moving) and your "side Bar" as the frontViewController (sliding on top, optionally transparent). From my understanding of what you want to achieve this is all you need.